Custom Intermediate Table Models - eager loading
Here is my current setup:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender',
        'birthdate', 'nationality_id', 'company_id',
    ];

    public function positions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Position::class)
            ->using(EmployeePosition::class);
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Position extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'positions';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function employees(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class)
            ->using(EmployeePosition::class);
    }
}


These connect to each other through a Pivot table, which is configured as "Custom Intermediate Table Models" according to docs.
I've set the following cols:
| id | employee_id | position_id |
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class EmployeePosition extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public    $incrementing = true;
    protected $table        = 'employee_position';
}


Having $employee, up to here it works fine:
$employee->load('positions')
Next, I also created a employee_position_technologies table:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployeePositionTechnology extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employee_position_technologies';

    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_position_id',
        'technology_id',
    ];
}


I want to assign many "technologies" to the "EmployeePosition".
I've also achieved that.
Now, what I am trying to achieve is load technologies to the Employee positions accordingly:
$employee->load('positions.technologies')
For this, I've modified the EmployeePosition class, adding the technologies() method like so:
    public function technologies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Technology::class,
            EmployeePositionTechnology::class,
            'employee_position_id',
            'id',
            'position_id',
            'technology_id'
        );
    }

this does not work, as the technologies() method seems to be searched from the
Position Model.
I've found that to access the "Intermediate Table Models" we have to use something like:
$employee->position->pivot->technologies
so I tried:
$employee->load('positions.pivot.technologies');
which also does not seem to work, with error
Call to undefined relationship [pivot] on model [App\Models\Position].
next, although I do not like it, I tried:
$employee->load('positions');

$employee->positions->each(function ($position) {
    $position->pivot->load('technologies');
});


This seems to work, and I can access the method, but the resulting technologies relation of the position is empty.
I tried to dump the query, and it seems correct:
select * from "technologies" 
inner join "employee_position_technologies" 
on "employee_position_technologies"."technology_id" = "technologies"."id" 
where "employee_position_technologies"."employee_position_id" = ?

what am I missing?

Have you tried using the with() method in place of load() method to eager load the relationship you are trying to load? You can achieve this using the with keyword as shown below where the relationship is passed as arguement to the with method
$employee->positions()->with('technologies')->get();

This will return all positions found for the employee along with the related technologies for each position if there are any. You can read more on using with method for eager loading from the Laravel official website

Just tried, but no. That is more or less the same as:
$employee->load('positions.technologies');
which returns error:
Call to undefined relationship [technologies] on model [App\Models\Position].
